# How to compute that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\exp(-\vert x\vert) \sin(ax)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\exp(-\vert x\vert)
\sin(ax)\,dx\quad\mbox{where}\
a\ \mbox{is a positive constant.}
$$
My idea is to use integration by parts. But I have been not handle three terms..
Please, help me solve that.

Comment: How about differentiating $$2\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-x)\cos(ax) \, dx$$w.r.t. $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or note
$$
2\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-x)
\sin(ax)\,dx
=
2\;\mathrm{Im}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp((-1+ia)x)\;dx
$$

Comment: Just like mine, so of course I will upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Since the function is symmetric,
$I(a)
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\exp(-\vert x\vert)
\sin(ax)\,dx
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-x)
\sin(ax)\,dx
$.

At this point, 
I would write
$\sin(ax)
=Im(e^{iax})
$
so that
$I(a)
=2Im\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-x)
e^{iax}\,dx
=2Im\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(x(-1+ia))dx
$
and try to evaluate
$\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp(-bx)dx
$,
which should not be too difficult.

Comment: All too easy.  +1 ....